# How can I monitor directories with an Azure FileTrigger

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-triggers

I have a WebJob that works fine with a FileTrigger pointing to a specific directory but I would like to monitor files added to all directories underneath it:

```
data
  |_ dir one (file added here)
  |_ dir two (file added here)
```

I currently have the trigger set up as:

```
[FileTrigger(@"data\{name}", "*", WatcherChangeTypes.Created, autoDelete: true)] string message,
```

I can only add one trigger (which makes absolute sense) and the following doesn't work either:

```
@"data\*\{name}"
```

What will be the best way to monitor those directories from a single WebJob?

Comment: Looking at the FileTrigger code https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions/Extensions/Files/Listener/FileListener.cs I don't see a way to set IncludeSubdirectories https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.includesubdirectories(v=vs.110).aspx to true in the FileSystemWatcher. So perhaps you can open a pull request about this in the GitHub repository.

Comment: Actually I am going to attempt to add separate functions to look at each directory so I need to know how to have "data\%app setting value%\{name}" as the trigger path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actually I am going to attempt to add separate functions to look at each directory so I need to know how to have "data\%app setting value%{name}" as the trigger path.

It seems that you could not use `data\%app setting value%\{name}` as the trigger path.

Because when you run webjobs, It will get the file path like `c:\temp\files\clients\%foldername%`,it will show the path does not exist. Error message as below:
[image]

So, I suggest that you could add separate functions in the same webjobs to look at each directory like:

```
public void TriggerTest([FileTrigger(@"data\dirone\{name}", "*", WatcherChangeTypes.Created)] Stream file, string name, TextWriter log)
```

When Webjobs runs, it will find all the functions in it and then job host start.

Comment: Yes that is where I have been but that approach does not resolve the issue as I still need to have different values as we deploy through different environments. We have separate structures for each "so called" environment. If thats not clear what I mean is that I need to be able to resolve part of the path at runtime. :(

Comment: I am going to accept this answer as it is spot on and what I have had to do. Can I request that resolving is added to the FileTrigger somewhere?

Comment: I am not clear about what the resolving you meant, for more details you could refer to the [webjob sdk extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions).

Comment: By resolving I mean that I am able to place the same "%<setting Name>%" in the FileTrigger annotation Which is currently not supported. How would I go about lodging a request like that?

Comment: You could go to feedback at this [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Comment: thanks I have done that https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/34780528-allow-patterns-in-filetrigger-bindings